# Median bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, sas, median

I ran a data set containing ages through SAS npar1way first, but a reviewer wanted standard errors, so that motivated a smooth bootstrap.  Since I could not use survyselect, I had to code a data step.  I think it's set up correctly.  I ran 10,000, 20,000 and 100,000 replicates.  I need some feedback on my findings.  The results I got weren't entirely satisfactory, but I don't have a lot of experience bootstrapping, so feedback is appreciated.  I have two groups, so first I split them, then drew my samples, combined everything and used by processing to obtain the results.

```
data sasdata.group1 sasdata.group2;
  set sasdata.have(keep=group ga birthwt);
  if group=1 then output sasdata.group1;
  if group=2 then output sasdata.group2;
run;

sasfile sasdata.group1 load;
data sasdata.outboot1(drop=__i);
  do Replicate = 1 to 100000;
    do __i = 1 to numrecs;
      p = int(1 + numrecs*(ranuni(62353006)));
      set sasdata.group1 point=p nobs=numrecs;
      a = a + rannor(623530)/sqrt(numrecs); /* 1 */
      output;
    end;
  end;
  stop;
run;
sasfile sasdata.group1 close;
ods listing close;

sasfile sasdata.group2 load;
data sasdata.outboot3(drop=__i);
  do Replicate = 1 to 100000;
    do __i = 1 to numrecs;
      p = int(1 + numrecs*(ranuni(17036255)));
      set sasdata.group2 point=p nobs=numrecs;
      a = a + rannor(170362)/sqrt(numrecs); /* 1 */
      output;
    end;
  end;
  stop;
run;
sasfile sasdata.group2 close;
ods listing close;

data sasdata.a; 
  set sasdata.outboot1 
      sasdata.outboot3;
run;

proc sort data=sasdata.a;
  by replicate group;
run;

ods listing close;
proc univariate data=sasdata.a;
  var a;
  by replicate group;
  output out=sasdata.aresults median=medianx;
run;
ods listing;

proc transpose data=sasdata.aresults (keep=replicate
                                            group
                                            medianx
                        )
  out=sasdata.t_results prefix=grp;
  by replicate;
  var medianx;
  id group;
run;

proc univariate data=sasdata.t_results;
  var grp1 grp2;
run;

data sasdata.median_diff;
  set sasdata.t_results;
  median_diff=grp1-grp2;
run;

proc univariate data=sasdata.median_diff /*noprint */;
  var median_diff;
  output out=sasdata.percentiles pctlpre=P_ pctlpts=2.5, 97.5;
run;
```

The medians just don't seem to match what I get from npar1way.  They're close, but slightly off; thus the difference in medians is slightly larger for the bootstrap 
case.  It doesn't seem right to report the npar1way medians and the bootstrap SEs given that the bootstrap does not converge to the actual medians. Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: I ran my data through Stata's bpmedian and bpdifmed and solved this problem.  I'm still not sure why my bootstrap doesn't work.  I ran a million replications and got the same results I got at 100,000, so it's converging.  There must be a problem with the algorithm.